@Inject lateinit var vs @Inject constructor on Dagger Hilt
Reading documentation, I found that it's possible to use Hilt by these two ways:

@Inject lateinit var on just the class fields you want to inject
@Inject constructor

I'm trying to figure out which option is better. I personally found an issue on @Inject constructor. When I need to pass non Hilt parameters to the constructor, it requires you to generate a lot of boilerplate code that only forces you to add more complexity to your project. For example:
Having a class like this:
@AndroidEntryPoint 
class CustomClass @Inject constructor (val repository: Repository, val name: String) {

Let's say I only want to inject the repository parameter, but I want to pass the name parameter during initialization like so:
val customClass = CustomClass("name")

with @Inject constructor I'm forced to add a lot of boirlerplate and complexity:
@AndroidEntryPoint 
class CustomClass @AssisgtedInject constructor (
    val repository: Repository, 
    @Assisted val name: String
) {

    @AssistedFactory
    interface CustomClassFactory {
        fun create(name: String): CustomClass
    }
}

To add more boilerplate and useless complexity, that forces you to create the CustomClass class with the interface instead of the normal class, and calling the create method.
On the other hand, if you instead do it using @Inject lateinit var, is that simple:
@AndroidEntryPoint 
class CustomClass(val name: String) {
    @Inject lateinit var repository: Repository
}

Now, think that this is a super simple example with just one non Hilt parameter, but this can get a lot more big as you know.
So, why almost every sample project is using @Inject constructor if @Inject lateinit var is a much more better option? What I'm missing here?

Its not like one is better than the other. Each have their pros and cons. I can see a few benefits of using the constructor based approach:

dependencies are immutable as you are not using var
easier to mock dependencies during test
has clear dependencies as they are present in the constructor and not somewhere inside the class.


The constructor method is almost universally preferred because it means a 1 step initialization vs a 2 step one.  In other words, if you create an instance of Foo, you know it has all of the data it needs to run.  Whereas with parameter injection, you could have called the Foo constructor but not initialized the injected data members, which leaves it in an inconsistent state.
What you're talking about with providing non-injected data in the constructor as well is called assisted injection.  It's useful.  But doing assisted injection via member variables rather than constructor magnifies the problem above-  every time you call Foo(), you have to then remember to inject it as well.  Or else you don't get those injected variables filled in.  You now have to remember to do two things every time you create an instance of the object, or you won't have them properly initialized.  You will get it wrong, especially in a bigger project.
The only time you shouldn't prefer constructor injection is when the object is being created via a framework that doesn't use Hilt/Dagger.  Then you have no choice.  An example is Activities.  But if you're creating the object, you should ALWAYS use constructor injection.

I don't understand you. "with parameter injection, you could have called the Foo constructor but not initialized the injected data members, which leaves it in an inconsistent state." What do you mean with that? In my sample of @Inject lateinit var, if I call val customClass = CustomClass("name"), the injected value is done automatically in simply the only and one step of that line. Because as a field, is initialized when the class is initialized. I don't need to do two steps, can't become inconsistent because the injection is done by the machine, not by the developer. Do I explain myself?

No, it's not.  WHen you call val customClass=CustomClass("name"), the injected values are NOT filled in.  You have to manually inject the object in this case.  Calling the constructor only calls the constructor.  It does not inject any member variables because it can't-  how would it know what context to use to inject it with?  Constructor injection works because it's all done at once at init time of the highest level variable.

I'm checking the official hilt documentation and the android guides and I can't see anywhere what you are telling. Can't find any line explaining that you must inject manually in another step each "@Inject lateinit" var. Can't find a sample of that. Please can you give me a link? Thanks

How do you think a constructor would inject those?  The constructor doesn't know the Dagger context to use to inject it.  There may not be just one global one.  So no, a constructor does not inject those fields.  It does inject when using constructor injection because in that case the injection framework is the one calling the constructor.  UNless you're doing it via hand rolled provider functions, in which case you're losing all the advantages of using Hilt over plain Dagger

But here is some info on field injection in Dagger (Hilt is built on top of Dagger and provides some automatic creation of contexts and modules):  https://dagger.dev/members-injection.html.  https://medium.com/@zuhayr.codes/field-injection-in-dagger2-di-day-2-41b03ecf439a    You'll see that a manual component.inject(object) is needed to inject the fields.

definitively you are wrong my friend, I tested it, adding a "@Inject lateinit var" on a class, an object that prints a log, very simple object for test injection, and it works, it prints the log, the inject works perfectly without two steps, all the injection process it's done automatically by Hilt... please test it, you will see that no two steps are needed. Simply with the lateinit var line the var is injected and can be used without passing it in a second step

@NullPointerException I've been using these frameworks for a decade, I'm not wrong.  Please tell me how the constructor would know what context to use to inject?  There doesn't have to be just one.  Calling a constructor does NOT inject the instance.  The sole exception are Android lifecycle classes that are annotated with @ AndroidEntryPoint.

BTW, my knowledge is more based on Dagger, which 100% works like this.  Maybe Hilt has some magic with assuming a single context... but in that case you lose so much flexibility and functionality of being able to create multiple scopes that the library would be garbage.  Unless you're doing something with inheritance where the base class does the injection, how would calling a constructor cause injection to happen?  Because unless you write that into your init function, that's not how Kotlin works.  Or Java.

You are right, I disscovered that my test only works with normal classes, but it doesn't work with viewmodel. For some reason, viewmodel do need an inject constructor when using field injection... so you are forced to use assisted injection. Unfortunatelly... I think I'll be forced to accomodate to assisted injection
